# ui grid date cellfilter, filtering date format is causing wrong date to show up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, filter, angular-ui-grid

http://plnkr.co/edit/2dJAoMULBKD6frSSW7FN?p=preview

Please have a look at the plunkr above

I have give data as

```
date = "2008-12-10T04:00:00.000Z"
```

and applied cellfilter

```
cellFilter: 'date:"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"',
```

however the ending result it is showing as 2008-12-09 23:00, it should show 2008-12-10 04:00?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the 'Z' that you putting in the strting Datetime. In this way you are indicating that this is a UTC date so that formatting transforms local.

You will get what you want if you change your code to:

```
date = "2008-12-10T04:00:00.000"
```